# Allow Spring controller to take over after Spring security authenticates user for user object post-auth processing?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my Spring 4 MVC Rest API application. 
I have implemented successfully the authentication process using java configurations. I have also managed to log in properly, and I have used JdbcTemplate to interface with my mysql database.

Tmy SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

I'm really struggling to understand how I should modify the above configuration to use it in a REST Api application. I need to manage the session for the android app these apis are to be used with, so that, for every request, I do not have to pass the user_id.
If anyone could possibly mention the preferred (standard) way of achieving this (with just enough details), I'll be really really glad :)

Comment: You could use jwt tokens in your spring authentication.  When you authenticate you'll receive a token back.  That token can be passed back and forth to allow access to the rest api.

Comment: here is an example project that uses jwt tokens. https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo

Comment: Is there anyhow I can also hit my controller for post-processing?

Comment: with your above config, you can say loginPage("/login").successForwardUrl("/successLogin") where it'll forward successful logins to a controller mapping.

Comment: Jwt seems like a potential choice here for me. Assigning successforwardurl also forwards me to the desired controller. I am now confused as to undertake which method to solve my problem. Any suggestions @jmw5598?

Comment: I'm still a beginner and learning but I'm actually working on a similar project where I have an Angular2 frontend and building a Spring REST api that the frontend authenticates and uses to pull data.  I went with JWT tokens and seems to be working great.  To me it seems like a token based authentication is the better approach.  You might also look into Spring Security's OAuth project.  I'm not familiar with it but have noticed its quite popular https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/